# I am confused why this implementation of mergesort isn't working?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am a novice in Haskell and I am trying to implement mergesort but it is not working, and I am confused as to why?

My code:

```
halve :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
halve xs = splitAt (length xs `div` 2) xs

merge :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
merge xs [] = xs
merge [] ys = ys
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) =
         if x < y
                 then x:(merge xs (y:ys))
                 else y:(merge (x:xs) ys)

msort :: [Int] -> [Int]
msort [] = []
msort xs 
    | length xs <= 1 = xs
    | otherwise      = merge (msort fst(halve xs)) (msort snd(halve xs))
```

In the `msort` main body, my understanding of how it should work is that if the length of `xs` is less than or equal to `1` then it returns the list. Otherwise, it halves the list `xs` and recursively starts `mosrt` again, until `length` is equal to or less than 1, at which point it applies merge to it.

What am I missing / how is that wrong?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Exactly *what* is not working?

Comment: `msort fst(halve xs)` is best written as `msort fst (halve xs)` which shows it is calling function `msort` with _two_ arguments, namely `fst`, and `halve xs`. This is clearly not what you want, so you need additional parentheses to apply `fst` first (as shown below in the answer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot brackets in your recursive `msort` calls:

```
msort :: [Int] -> [Int]
msort xs 
    | length xs <= 1 = xs
    | otherwise = merge (msort (fst (halve xs))) (msort (snd (halve xs)))
```

That being said, using `length` is often *not* a good idea, since it runs in *O(n)*. It is better to use pattern matching here. Furthermore you can use a `where` clause to avoid calculating `halve xs` twice:

```
msort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
msort [] = []
msort [x] = [x]
msort xs = merge (msort la) (msort lb)
    where (la, lb) = halve xs
```

The `halve` can be constructed where we pass every second element to one of the elements of the 2-tuple, like:

```
halve :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
halve [] = ([], [])
halve (x:xs) = (x:ya, yb)
    where (yb, ya) = halve xs
```

or with a `foldr` pattern:

```
halve :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
halve = foldr (\x (yb, ya) -> (x:ya, yb)) ([], [])
```

and the `merge` can be implemented more elegantly by using *as-patterns*:

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] ys = ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge xa@(x:xs) ya@(y:ys)
    | x <= y = x : merge xs ya
    | otherwise = y : merge xa ys
```